# Ways to buy an iOS subscription outside of an app

Tags: in-app-purchase

Im working on an app which will support subscribing to a premium version.
Whenever a user buys a subscription I can verify the receipt on my backend, persist important data and grant entitlement which is good.
However, when a user buys the subscription for the first time I rely on the Firebase User ID in order to query my DB.
When I receive App Store server notifications I query by the original_transaction_id.
Now comes the problem, I do not know whether a subscription can be bought initially outside of my app. (I only sell them in-app, but am not sure if apple provides a way to buy them outside of the app.).
If it is possible it would cause a problem.

Comment: Apple does not provide a method to purchase subscriptions outside your app. Note that users must not be *required* to create an account to use in app purchases.

Comment: thank you @Paulw11 that is some crucial information!